# How Do I Calculate these Variables? (See equation below)

Tags: vectors, perturbation-theory

Specifically, I am having trouble calculating Omega perpendicular and g perpendicular. I know that g is the reciprocal lattice vector and Omega is the unit vector of the direction of X-ray emission. What does the perpendicular sign mean, and how would I go about calculating these values?

Thanks so much in advance!

[image]

Comment: Posting images of text and equations is *very* strongly discouraged on this site as the site search engine cannot usefully interpret images.  Please use text and [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead.

Comment: Please note the site [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to try and find symbols you don't know how to write in Mathjax.